# How can I display json object with {"id":"value"} instead of {"col1":"id","col2:"value"}

Tags: mysql, json

So I am making multilingual site using [languages.js.org](http://languages.js.org), with a database named `ft_main` table `ft_lang` with translation contains 2 columns: id, en.

Using JSON, I can display JSON Object from my database like this:

```
{"id":"1","en":"First translation"},
{"id":"2","en":"Second translation"},
{"id":"3","en":"Third translation"},
...
```

But languages.js won't run with the object format like above, it will run with format like this:

```
{"1":"First translation"},
{"2":"Second translation"},
{"3":"Third translation"},
...
```

So how can I use JSON to display object with the format like I mentioned above from my database?

Comment: Don't think you can, because the format you desire isn't JSON.

Comment: What problem are you having creating the JSON the way you need it? Just use one column as the keys and the other column as the values, instead of putting them in separate properties.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `{"1": "First", "2": "Second", ...}`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I want them to be seperate, not in 1 object

Comment: I am making an example, my database have "id" column as key, the rest are values

Comment: Are both of those examples supposed to be elements in an array that you haven't shown? By themselves it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Base on the documentation of that languages.js, the json must have format {"id":"text"}, so i want to show json from my database just like that format {"1":"First"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to simplify the code:

```js
var data = [
  {"id":"1","en":"First translation"},
  {"id":"2","en":"Second translation"},
  {"id":"3","en":"Third translation"}];
var newData = data.map(obj => ({[obj.id]: obj.en}));
console.log(newData);
```

Explanation:

- `data.map(fn)` applies the function `fn` to each element in the `data` array, and returns the results in an array of the same size.
- `obj => ({[obj.id]: obj.en})` is a translation that takes an `obj` and returns an object containing a single property, with `obj.id` as the key and `obj.en` as the value.

  - This is what turns `{"id": "foo", "en": "bar"}` into `{"foo": "bar"}`.
  - The outer `()` are required because otherwise JavaScript will try to treat what's within `{}` as a function.
  - The `[]` are required around `obj.id` so the parser knows the whole key is `obj.id` and not `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to iterate through the array and create a new one like this:

```js
var data = [
{"id":"1","en":"First translation"},
{"id":"2","en":"Second translation"},
{"id":"3","en":"Third translation"}];
var newData = [];
data.forEach(function(obj) {
  var newObj = {};
  newObj[obj.id] = obj.en;
  newData.push(newObj);
});
console.log(newData);
```